# Regex pattern with variable not working

Tags: javascript, regex, concatenation

The following regex correctly extracts the path between the quotes.

```
const value = 'image-width("image-path.jpg")';
const result = value.match(/image-width\(['"]?(.+?)['"]?\)/)[1];

console.log(result); // image-path.jpg
```

But I need to make it more DRY because `image-width` might not always be the same, so I've made a function to make it possible for `image-width` to be a variable

```
function getPath(value, wrapper) {
    const regexString = `${wrapper}\\(['"]?(.+?)['"]?\\)`; // deliberate double back slash
    const patternMatch = new RegExp(regexString, 'g'); // /image-width\(['"]?(.+?)['"]?\)/g (which is the same as the working regex value above
    return value.match(patternMatch)[1]; // undefined
}

const path = getPath('image-width("image-path.jpg")', 'image-width'); // undefined
```

This doesn't work and `path` is just undefined.

Comment: `replace` does not occur anywhere in the code given

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Sorry, I've amended the last part of the question to say `path` is just undefined.

Comment: Seems to me you get 0 matches so maybe your regex is wrong? What exactly is the value of patternMatch?

Comment: @AndréKool `patternMatch` == `/image-width\(['"]?(.+?)['"]?\)/g` which is the same as the first working regular expression above it (minus the `g` modifier on the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the use of `match()` with the `g` modifier

#### Broken using `.match()`

```
function getPath(value, wrapper) {
    const regexString = `${wrapper}\\(['"]?(.+?)['"]?\\)`;
    const patternMatch = new RegExp(regexString, 'g');
    return value.match(patternMatch)[1];
}

const path = getPath('image-width("image-path.jpg")', 'image-width'); // undefined
```

#### Fixed using `.exec()`

```
function getPath(value, wrapper) {
    const regexString = `${wrapper}\\(['"]?(.+?)['"]?\\)`;
    const patternMatch = new RegExp(regexString, 'g');
    return patternMatch.exec(value)[1]; // Use exec() instead
}

const path = getPath('image-width("image-path.jpg")', 'image-width'); // image-path.jpg
```